# Python - Split a list of integers into positive and negative

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm learning python and i wanted to know whats the way to to split a list like :

```
A = [1, -3, -2, 8, 4, -5, 6, -7]
```

into two lists, one containing positive and the other one containing negative integers :

```
B = [1, 8, 4, 6]
C = [-3, -2, -5, -7]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this in O(n) using a `defaultdict()`:

```
In [3]: from collections import defaultdict

In [4]: d = defaultdict(list)

In [5]: for num in A:
   ...:     if num < 0:
   ...:         d['neg'].append(num)
   ...:     else: # This will also append zero to the positive list, you can change the behavior by modifying the conditions 
   ...:         d['pos'].append(num)
   ...:         

In [6]: d
Out[6]: defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'neg': [-3, -2, -5, -7], 'pos': [1, 8, 4, 6]})
```

Another way is using two separate list comprehensions (not recommended for long lists):

```
>>> B,C=[i for i in A if i<0 ],[j for j in A if j>0]
>>> B
[-3, -2, -5, -7]
>>> C
[1, 8, 4, 6]
```

Or as a purely functional approach you can also use [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) as following:

```
In [19]: list(filter((0).__lt__,A))
Out[19]: [1, 8, 4, 6]

In [20]: list(filter((0).__gt__,A))
Out[20]: [-3, -2, -5, -7]
```

Comment: I think we can do it with a single for loop instead of two for loops

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford iterating over `A` twice, list comprehensions are best IMO:

```
B = [x for x in A if x >= 0]
C = [x for x in A if x < 0]
```

Of course there's always the "manual" way:

```
A = [1, -3, -2, 8, 4, -5, 6, -7]
B = []
C = []
for x in A:
    if (x >= 0):
        B.append(x)
    else:
        C.append(x)
```

Comment: Even if you *can't* afford to iterate over `A` twice, iterating over `A` twice is still probably the best.

Answer (score 0):

we can use a function to separate +ve numbers and -ve numbers with a single for loop

```
def separate_plus_minus(numbers_list):
    positive = []
    negative = []
    for number in numbers_list:
        if number >= 0:
             positive.append(number)
        else:
             negative.append(number)
    return positive, negative
```

usuage:

```
numbers_list = [-1,5,6,-23,55,0,25,-10]
positive, negative = separate_plus_minus(numbers_list)
```

Output:

```
positve = [5, 6, 55, 0, 25]
negative = [-1, -23, -10]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def manipulate_data(alist):
      fo = []
      go = []
      for i in alist:
            if i < 0:
                  fo.append(i)
          #elif(i > 0):
               #    go.append(i)
      print fo
    for i in alist:
            if i > 0:
                  go.append(i)
      print go

def main():
      alist = [54,26,-93,-17,-77,31,44,55,20]
      manipulate_data(alist)

if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it using conditionals in list comprehension like this:

```
k = [1, -3, 5, 9, -1, 3, -3, -2]
positive = list()
negative = [i for i in k if i < 0 or (i > 0 and positive.append(i))]
```

I'm pretty sure this is O(n) and this is only two lines.

Answer (score 0):

we can use lambda as following:

```
list(filter(lambda x: 0 > x, A))
Output: [-3, -2, -5, -7]

list(filter(lambda x: 0 <= x, A))
Output: [1, 8, 4, 6]
```

we have to change the equation(0 <= x) to (0 < x) to avoid 0 in positive numbers list.

Comment: Using previous answer with list comprehension is shorter, and without the need of lambda nor filter function.